# Simple/ Primitive Tetragonal Bravais Lattice

Tags: crystal-structure

Are there any elements which exhibit the Simple(Primitive) Tetragonal Bravais Lattice?

Comment: base-centered cubic lattice can be redrawn as a primitive tetragonal lattice, therefore we do not include it in the list of Bravais lattices.    Is from [here](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/47834/why-can-a-face-centered-cubic-lattice-not-be-redrawn-as-a-body-centered-tetragon)

Comment: How is there a base-centered cubic lattice?  Cubic lattices are supposed to be primitive, fcc or bcc.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why can a face-centered cubic lattice not be redrawn as a body-centered tetragonal lattice?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/47834/why-can-a-face-centered-cubic-lattice-not-be-redrawn-as-a-body-centered-tetragon)

Comment: Colleagues, please consider reopening this question. Just how is it "too broad"? It asks one specific thing in no uncertain terms, and has a clear answer, even if my own answer could have made it seem otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chances are there are no such elements. [This link](http://periodictable.com/Properties/A/CrystalStructure.html) seems to suggest so, but I wouldn't put too much trust in it. (To begin with, it claims only one crystal structure for each element, ignoring any polymorphs.) **So what?** This is not a fact of any consequence. It is about as (un)important as the knowledge that only one of the element names in English starts with "K", and none start with "J". Besides, both may change over time. New high-pressure crystal modifications of elements are discovered every now and then, and will be for a while, because no matter how far you reach, there is always a higher pressure.

Come to think of it, there are *millions* of different crystal structures out there. Elemental compounds are just a very tiny minority. Surely there are examples of all Bravais lattices (not that it matters much).

So it goes.