What is the precise definition of crystal systems and unit cell?
I was just wondering why there wasn't a rhombic 2D Bravais unit cell (wasn't there in the material provided to us) and realised upon drawing that it is the same as a centered rectangular unit cell. Upon reading on the internet (Wikipedia included) it seems they don't mention a rhombic unit cell just the rectangular centered. We consider such a lattice as part of the rectangular system (hence rectangular centered).
I don't understand why this is fair for 2 reasons-

Shouldn't we generally prefer the primitive cell given same symmetries?
If both unit cells are correct (How?) then why is trigonal(rhombic) considered part of
the rectangular system? (what is a crystal system is it defined solely on symmetry?)
While in 3D trigonal and rectangular are distinct?


Related: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/47834/why-can-a-face-centered-cubic-lattice-not-be-redrawn-as-a-body-centered-tetragon/47868#47868
